# How to pass array of integers from Tcl to C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, tcl, ns2

How do I send Tcl array to C++? I have written the following code:

#### Tcl:

```
set ns [new Simulator]


    set n [$ns node]
$n set X_ 100
$n set Y_ 30
$n set Z_ 0
set x [$n set X_]
set y [$n set Y_]
set z [$n set Z_]
#after 2000
set b {12 2 3 4 5}

set aa [new "Application/Trust/ITLeach"]
$aa set bufer_ 1
$aa set allnode_ $n
$aa set X_ $x
$aa set Y_ $y
$aa set Z_ $z
$aa set ClausterHeadID_   [array get b] **#send array to c++**
$ns at 0.0 "$aa start"
puts $b
$ns run
```

#### ITLEACH.h:

```
#ifndef ns_ITLeach_h
#define ns_ITLeach_h
#include "app.h"
#include "node.h"
#include "tcl.h"
#include "mobilenode.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
class ITLeach;
#define TCL_OK 0
class ITLeach : public  Application {
 public:
    ITLeach();


  virtual int command(int argc, const char*const* argv);

 protected:
  // need to define recv and timeout
  void start();
  int Buffer;
  MobileNode * node ;
  ofstream nodeSetting;
  double XPos ;
  double YPos ;
  double ZPos ;
  int ClausterHeadID [] ; //int array that passed from tcl file
  int  ClausterID [] ;
  int id_node;
};


#endif
```

#### ITLEACH.cc:

```
/*
 * ITLeach.cc
 *
 *  Created on: Oct 29, 2013
 *      Author: root
 */

#include "ITLeach.h"
static class ITLeachClass : public TclClass {
public:
    ITLeachClass() : TclClass("Application/Trust/ITLeach") {}
    TclObject* create(int, const char*const*) {
        return (new ITLeach());
    }
} class_app_ITLeach;

ITLeach::ITLeach() : Application() {
    Tcl_Obj *baObj = Tcl_NewObj();
bind("bufer_",&Buffer);
bind("allnode_",&node);
bind("X_",&XPos);
bind("Y_",&YPos);
bind("Z_",&ZPos);
bind("ClausterHeadID_",(int *) &ClausterHeadID); // call array from tcl
bind("ClausterID_",ClausterID);
bind("id_",&id_node);

}

int ITLeach::command(int argc, const char*const* argv) {

        if (strcmp(argv[1], "start") == 0) {
            ITLeach::start();
            return(TCL_OK);
        }



      return(ITLeach::command(argc, argv));
    }
void ITLeach::start()
{
//double x=0, y =0 , z =0;
    nodeSetting.open("./leachnode.txt",fstream::app);

        //node = (MobileNode*)Node::get_node_by_address(i);
//node->location()->getLocation(x,y,z);
//node->getLoc(&x,&y,&z);
        nodeSetting << "id " << id_node << " x "<< XPos << " y " << YPos << " z " << ZPos <<"\n";



    nodeSetting.close();

    printf(" claster head number : %d \n" ,ClausterHeadID[1]);
    printf("node number is : %d \n",Buffer);
}
```

I send array from Tcl with this code:

```
$aa set ClausterHeadID_   [array get b] **#send array to c++**
```

and receive array from C++ with this code:

```
bind("ClausterHeadID_",(int *) &ClausterHeadID); // call array from tcl
```

But it doesn't work, please help me.

Comment: "*It doesn't work*" is not a sufficient problem description. Please explain *exactly* what happens, including any error messages or outputs.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got that command bound to the string interface (i.e., the arguments arrive via `int argc, char **argv`) then you use `Tcl_SplitList()` to take apart the relevant argument (which might be `argv[argc-1]`, i.e., the last argument) and then `Tcl_GetInt()` to retrieve an integer from each of those values. Those integers are the members of that Tcl list.

```
int listc;
char **listv;
if (Tcl_SplitList(interp, argv[argc-1], &listc, &listv) != TCL_OK) {
    // wasn't a valid list!
    return TCL_ERROR;
}
std::vector<int> theArray(listc, 0);
for (int i=0 ; i<listc ; i++) {
    if (Tcl_GetInt(interp, listv[i], &theArray[i]) != TCL_OK) {
        // wasn't an int in the list!
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }
}
```

This isn't very fast! For a faster way, you need to use the `Tcl_Obj`-based API (the `Tcl_Obj` is the fundamental Tcl first-class value type), starting with registering your implementation function correctly. After that, it's fairly easy to convert the above code:

```
int listc;
Tcl_Obj **listv;
if (Tcl_ListObjGetElements(interp, argv[argc-1], &listc, &listv) != TCL_OK) {
    // wasn't a valid list!
    return TCL_ERROR;
}
std::vector<int> theArray(listc, 0);
for (int i=0 ; i<listc ; i++) {
    if (Tcl_GetIntFromObj(interp, listv[i], &theArray[i]) != TCL_OK) {
        // wasn't an int in the list!
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }
}
```

The big difference? A `Tcl_Obj` knows whether it is holding a string or an integer (or a float or any number of other things) and so the Tcl runtime doesn't normally need to reparse or type-convert values, whereas if everything is a string, you do a lot of conversions. (It's common to say “*Everything is a string*” in Tcl, but that's inaccurate; the correct version is “*Everything has a perfect string serialization, or is a named entity*” but that's rather more verbose.)

Comment: The `TclClass` class probably needs some work doing on it to make it `Tcl_Obj` aware.